# WebGL Fillstyle

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl

I currently have a canvas to which I am rendering a ThreeJS scene. Everything is working fine, however, I would like to display a transparent fill over it.

With a normal canvas, I would simply do

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

This, of course, doesn't work because I'm using WebGL and the context is different. But I try to apply fillStyle to

```
renderer.context
```

Nothing happens.
I checked via console and the property does appear in the context as so

```
WebGLRenderingContext {fillStyle: "rgba(204, 61, 202, 0.7 )", canvas: canvas#canvas, drawingBufferWidth: 475, drawingBufferHeight: 397}
```

But still, the color doesn't appear.

Any idea if this is even possible?

Link to example http://creativiii.com/

Comment: `fillStyle` has nothing to do with WebGL. This is a property of the Canvas 2D API.

Comment: right so what do I use to apply a transparent color over a webgl canvas?

Comment: You can apply a simple post processing pass which will give you most flexibility in visual appearance.

Comment: I learned how to apply shaders but I have no idea how to actually write one. Any resources where I can find a way to apply a transparent color over my whole scene?

Comment: This a basic post processing example without `EffectComposer`. First, you render your scene into a render target. Next, you apply the post processing by using the render target as an input texture for your custom shader. https://jsfiddle.net/mrzp9nvd/2/

Comment: you can also just overlay another element over the webgl canvas

Comment: @gman Can you tell something about the performance aspects of this approach? I remember a case some years ago where the final compositing of the canvas and overlying transparent HTML elements caused performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xcc3dca, 0.7)
renderer.clear()
```