# d3fc webgl candlesticks - setting fillStyle equivelant in webgl

Tags: d3fc

I'm using d3fc+canvas to render candlesticks to a chart and change their fill color based on whether it's an up or down candle. The series generator looks like this

```
const generator = fc.seriesCanvasCandlestick()
        .crossValue(d => d.date)
        .openValue(d => d.open)
        .highValue(d => d.high)
        .lowValue(d => d.low)
        .closeValue(d => d.close)
        .decorate((context, datum, index) => {

            context.fillStyle = datum.close > datum.open ? 'blue' : 'red'
        });
```

I'm now trying to convert this to webGl rendering (using `seriesWebglCandlestick`) but I don't know how to set the fill color in the same way.

How can I convert my decorate function to color the webgl candlesticks?

It seems like I can get the Webgl context using context.context() but setting the fillStyle on it doesnt do anything.

I saw [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993848/webgl-fillstyle) suggest:

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xcc3dca, 0.7)
renderer.clear()
```

But there seems to be no `setClearColor` function on the Webgl context (though I do see `clear()`)

I also do see [`clearColor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/clearColor) which expects 4 arguments so I tried passing rgba values like `clearColor(197,197,197,0.7)` but also has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now this functionality has been released, the code should look like this -

```
const fillColor = fc
    .webglFillColor()
    .data(data)
    .value(d => 
         d.close > d.open ? 
             [0, 0, 1, 1] : [1, 0, 0, 1]
    );

const series = fc
    .seriesWebglCandlestick()
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .context(gl)
    .crossValue((_, i) => i)
    .highValue(d => d.high)
    .lowValue(d => d.low)
    .openValue(d => d.open)
    .closeValue(d => d.close)
    .decorate(program => {
        fillColor(program);
    });
```

N.B. webglFillColor will have no effect if there's no fill e.g. for ohlc. In that case you'll need to use webglStrokeColor .

Original answer below.

---

Unfortunately this isn't currently easy with the WebGL series in d3fc but we do expect that to [change shortly](https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/issues/1427).

As it stands this requires delving pretty deeply into the internals of the d3fc-webgl package. We don't recommend doing this currently (until the issue above is fixed) because the naming and exact functionality of components is liable to change.

However, if you're very keen to try this out here's the code required in the current version -

> This code will only run if you build your own version of the library to export `elementConstantAttributeBuilder` from `packages/d3fc-webgl/index.js`

```
const fillColorAttribute = fc
    .elementConstantAttributeBuilder()
    .size(4)
    .data(data)
    .value((data, element) => 
         data[element].close > data[element].open ? 
             [0, 0, 1, 1] : [1, 0, 0, 1]
    );

const series = fc
    .seriesWebglCandlestick()
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .context(gl)
    .crossValue((_, i) => i)
    .highValue(d => d.high)
    .lowValue(d => d.low)
    .openValue(d => d.open)
    .closeValue(d => d.close)
    .decorate(program => {
        program
            .vertexShader()
            .appendHeader('attribute vec4 aFillColor;')
            .appendHeader('varying vec4 vFillColor;')
            .appendBody('vFillColor = aFillColor;');
        program
            .fragmentShader()
            .appendHeader('varying vec4 vFillColor;')
            .appendBody('gl_FragColor = vFillColor;');
        program
            .buffers()
            .attribute('aFillColor', fillColorAttribute);
    });
```

Which produces the following -

[image: candlestick example showing blue/red fill color]

Comment: Thank you. Do the changes in https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/pull/1451 allow this answer to be updated? I've cloned the webgl branch locally and I'm trying to use fillColor.js but having trouble. How is this new code used?

Comment: Do I initialize it like so: ```const fillColorWebgl = fillColor().value((data, element) => data[element].close > data[element].open ? [0, 0, 1, 1] : [1, 0, 0, 1]);```  And then pass the program in the webgl series's decorate function: ```...decorate(program => fillColorWebgl(program))```? I'm getting programBuilder.context is no defined.

Comment: I'll update the answer properly when we release the code. It should be used like so -
`
const fillColor = fc.webglFillColor()
    .data(data)
    .value(d =>
        d.close > d.open ?
            [0, 0, 1, 1] : [1, 0, 0, 1]
    );

const series = fc
    .seriesWebglCandlestick()
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .context(gl)
    .crossValue((_, i) => i)
    .highValue(d => d.high)
    .lowValue(d => d.low)
    .openValue(d => d.open)
    .closeValue(d => d.close)
    .decorate(program => {
        fillColor(program);
    });
`

Comment: could you please update this answer now that the change has been released.